# How to send information to a singleton form before showing the form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, singleton

In a MDI WinForms environment with several multipurpose child forms everybody says that the easy way to keep only one instance of these forms openened in the same time is to have a Singleton implementation for this. After some searches I found this approach (VB .NET language):

```
Public Class FormSingleton(Of TForm As {Form, New})
    Private Shared _instance As TForm

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Form() As TForm
        Get
            If _instance Is Nothing OrElse _instance.IsDisposed Then
                _instance = New TForm
            End If

            Return _instance
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Sub Show()
        'Ensure the form is visible and has focus.
        With Form
            .Show()
            .Activate()
        End With
    End Sub

End Class
```

And of course, the code for showing the form will be:

```
FormSingleton(Of MyForm).Show()
```

Now the question I have is how to send some information to the "Singleton" form before the form is actually showed. The type of information has to be sent is different from one form to another.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add to your class `FormSingleton` a method such as...

```
Public Shared Sub AddFacts(ByVal fact_object As Object)
    With Form
        .AddFacts(fact_object)
    End With
End Sub
```

and then add a suitable `AddFacts` to each of your forms. It may be worthwhile looking into having your forms implement [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x(v=vs.71).aspx) and having the AddFacts, Show and Activate methods as part of that interface. That way you can ensure at compile time the form will be suitable for use in your singleton.

Comment: Besides to write a method for each form... the challenge is to figure how to make this method to be available from the base Form class because `AddFacts` is not a member of the Form class and an error is occurred, of course.

Comment: @ValentinVucea Hmmm...good point. Perhaps need to derive MyForm from Form, add the new method to it, and then have FormSingleton (Of TForm {MyForm, New}). But this may all be getting a bit much like hard work.